# Setting the "Description" on a Document Library using PnP PowerShell for SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to set the description on a Document Library in SharePoint Online using the PnP-PowerShell Commands, but it seems to be very intermittent in working, so I wanted to check what the correct way to do it is?

I create a new library with:

```
New-PnPList -Template DocumentLibrary -Title "TempLibrary"
```

Then try to set the Description with:

```
$l = Get-PnPList -Identity TempLibrary
$l.Description = "My Description Here"
```

Now clearly that doesn't work since I need to send the changes back with CSOM I assume?

So then I tried the following:

```
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$l = Get-PnPList -Identity TempLibrary
$l.Description = "My Description Here"
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

But this still didn't seem to work.

Any thoughts anyone has on how to do this reliably would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
D.

#### UPDATE

Eurgh... This seems to work, but is this right?  Is it expected?  Doesn't feel very PowerShell like...

```
New-PnPList -Title "Test5" -Template DocumentLibrary
$t = Get-PnPList -Identity Test5
$ctx.Load($t)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$t.Description = "Test5 Description"
$t.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without loading the list you will not be able to set the description or other properties so the code is correct.

```
$ctx.Load($t)
```

Why do you think this is not PS like? :) Curious...

Comment: Don't know really.  I think I would just assume that there might be a `Set-PnPListProperty` command or something that lets you set properties and does the load and execute query commands.  After all, I don't have to use Load and ExecuteQuery when I use the other Set-PnP* commands...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script. Hope it helps.

```
    Add - PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell  

    function CreateList($spWeb, $listName) 
    {   
        $spTemplate = $spWeb.ListTemplates["Document Library"]  
        $spListCollection = $spWeb.Lists  
        $spListCollection.Add($listName, $listName, $spTemplate)  
    }  

    Function SetDescription($spWeb, $listName)
    {            
        $path = $spWeb.url.trim()  
        $spList = $spWeb.GetList("$path/Lists/$listName")
        $spList.Description = "--Your Desired Description--"
        $spList.Update()
    }


    $siteCollectionUrl = "--Your Site Collection Url--"  
    $listName = "--Your Desired List Name--"  
    $spWeb = Get - SPWeb - Identity $siteCollectionUrl 

    CreateList $spWeb $listName 

    SetDescription $spWeb $listName
```

Comment: This is not PNP, which connects to SharePoint remotely without having to be on the SharePoint servers. Very useful if you don't have server access and want to work within the site collections.  read more here [link](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/readme.md)